# How should one try and fix bugs in Ubuntu?

Tags: launchpad, users

Given that it can take ages for the software engineers at Ubuntu to fix bugs once they are filed, if the user himself or herself wants to fix the bugs in ones system, what are the steps that he or she needs to take?

Answer (score 0):

You should get set up with Ubuntu Development.  [This would be a good starting point.](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/fixing-a-bug.html)